# Failed assertion: line 464 pos 12: 'needsCompositing': is not true. How to solve this problem?

Tags: flutter, audio, audio-player

I iniciant in flutter. I want to insert a audio play in app, but it not worked.  I'm using the library  **"assets_audio_player: ^3.1.1"** because my class is **'StatelessWidget'**. I thinked the error cause is the **FlexibleSpaceBar** widget, but I don't a solution. When I run this code occur this error:  ***'Failed assertion: line 464 pos 12: 'needsCompositing': is not true."***

**Error:**

```
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
'package:flutter/src/material/flexible_space_bar.dart': Failed assertion: line 464 pos 12: 'needsCompositing': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.yml

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FlexibleSpaceBar FlexibleSpaceBar:file:///C:/Users/ruama.patricio/AndroidStudioProjects/shopping/lib/pages/course.page.dart:131:30
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      _RenderFlexibleSpaceHeaderOpacity.paint (package:flutter/src/material/flexible_space_bar.dart:464:12)
#3      RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3155:7)
#4      PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:252:13)
#5      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2875:15)
#6      RenderStack.paintStack (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:639:5)
#7      PaintingContext.pushClipRect.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:535:83)
#8      ClipContext._clipAndPaint (package:flutter/src/painting/clip.dart:25:12)
#9      ClipContext.clipRectAndPaint (package:flutter/src/painting/clip.dart:53:5)
```

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';

var url = 'https://www.kozco.com/tech/LRMonoPhase4.mp3';
final audioo = AssetsAudioPlayer();

playAudiofromAssets() {
  print("Played");
  audioo.open(
    Audio('assets/audios/ash.mp3'),
  );
  audioo.playOrPause();
}

playAudiofromInt() {
  print("p");
  audioo.open(Audio.network(url));
}

stopAudio() {
  audioo.pause();
}



class CheckboxProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isChecked = false;

  bool get isChecked => _isChecked;

  set isChecked(bool value) {
    _isChecked = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
class CheckboxProviderAudio with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isCheckedAudio = false;

  bool get isCheckedAudio => _isCheckedAudio;

  set isCheckedAudio(bool value) {
    _isCheckedAudio = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}




class CoursePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String logo;
  final String details;
  final String company;


  CoursePage({
    required this. title,
    required this.description,
    required this.image,
    required this.logo,
    required this.details,
    required this.company,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled){
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              leadingWidth: 400,
              leading: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[

                  Flexible(

                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:4),
                      child:  InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Ink.image(
                          image: AssetImage("assets/item-voltar.png"),
                          width: 40,
                          height: 40,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Spacer(),


                 Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                      child:  InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                       //   Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Ink.image(
                          image: AssetImage("assets/component.png"),
                          width: 80,
                          height: 40,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              backgroundColor:  Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
              elevation: 0.0,
              expandedHeight: 500.0,
              floating: false,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                background: Hero(
                  tag: image,
                  child:  Image.asset(
                    image,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ];

        },
        body:ListView(
          children: <Widget> [
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                  child:  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      //   Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Ink.image(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/item-compartilhar.png"),
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(description,
                   style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),),
              ),
             Text("                             Por: "),
              Image.asset(logo, width: 50, height: 50,),

            ],

          ),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10,
                    left: 10,
                    right: 10
                ),
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 26,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
            ),

            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Icon(Icons.account_balance),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text(
                    company,
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),


            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text(
                  "Sobre",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text(
               details,
              ),
            ),


      Row(children: [
        Flexible(
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[ description  == " Curso"
              ? Row(
                children: [
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (_) => CheckboxProvider(),
                    child: Consumer<CheckboxProvider>(
                      builder: (context, checkboxProvider, _) => Checkbox(
                        value: checkboxProvider.isChecked,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          checkboxProvider.isChecked = value ?? true;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Text(
                    "Fiz esse curso",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),



                ],

              )
                :Row(
                    children: [
                      ChangeNotifierProvider(
                        create: (_) => CheckboxProviderAudio(),
                        child: Consumer<CheckboxProviderAudio>(
                          builder: (context, checkboxProviderAudio, _) => Checkbox(
                            value: checkboxProviderAudio.isCheckedAudio,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              checkboxProviderAudio.isCheckedAudio = value ?? true;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      Text(
                        "Já ouvi esse tutorial",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                  ],
            )
                ),
         ],
      ),


         Padding(
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[ description  == " Curso"
                  ?
                Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 400,
               /* decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),*/
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                child: Column(
                  children: [


                    Flexible(child:  TextButton(
                    child: Row(

                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.link, color: Colors.white,),
                        Text(
                          "Tenho Interesse",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    style:  const ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.cyan),

                    ),
                    onPressed: () => {},
                  ),

                  ),





                   Flexible(child:
                    TextButton(
                      child: Row(

                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.calendar_month, color: Colors.white,),
                          Text(
                            "Adicionar ao calendário",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      style:  const ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.lightBlueAccent),

                      ),
                      onPressed: () => {},
                    ),
                    )

                   
                  ],
                ),

              )
                : Text("Áudio Player"),
            Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                                 Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        "PLAY AUDIO FROM ASSET",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: <Widget>[


                                          TextButton.icon(
                                            onPressed: playAudiofromAssets,
                                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                              foregroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                                            ),
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                                            label: Text(""),

                                          ),

                                          Spacer(),

                                          TextButton.icon(
                                            onPressed: stopAudio,
                                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                              foregroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                                            ),
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
                                            label: Text(""),

                                          ),

                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Spacer(),
                                      Text(
                                        "PLAY AUDIO FROM INTERNET",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          TextButton.icon(
                                            //onPressed:(){},
                                           onPressed: () async {
                                              await audioo.open(Audio.network(url));
                                            },
                                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                              foregroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                                            ),
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                                            label: Text(""),
                                          ),

                                        Spacer(),
                                          TextButton.icon(
                                            onPressed:stopAudio,
                                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                              foregroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                                            ),
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
                                            label: Text(""),
                                          ),

                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),

                    ],

                    )

         ],
          ),
         ),
          ],

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to solve this problem or meet a new solution to insert a audio player in my app

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, and the solution I've made was to set:

```
backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
```

After I did some debugging to grasp the situation, I requested Gemini to clarify, and it responded:

> Ensure Opacity is Set Correctly:
>
> The FlexibleSpaceBar relies on compositing layers for certain opacity effects.
>
> Make sure the opacity property of the FlexibleSpaceBar is set to a value between 0.0 (fully transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque). Setting it to null or omitting it might trigger this error.

So, do not set the background to transparent (or equivalent).